# Cannot Locate Document in Jive File System

Tags: jive

Hi I am trying to find a Jive document in an export file of our old Jive instance.  I am able to query the Jive DBs, and have found the document in the database, but cannot locate the actual file.  My query results follow:

[image]

I attempted to follow the instructions here, https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-168808#jive_content_id_Step_3__Generate_the_name_of_the_file_in_the_file_storage_system_based_on_the_attachment_ID, but none of these ID values can be found in the \mnt\jive_binstore directory.  I attempted to find the number strings backwards like in the attachment example, adding 45 to the document id 27687 -> 4527687 then reversing it 7867254 but do not find anything that matches that is a document.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason this method was not working is this is how Jive stores attachments and other items that are images or files of types other than documents.  Documents are actually stored as HTML in a column on the documents table in the Jive database.